# Solving $(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^3)(1+x^4)....(1+x^n)$

Tags: polynomials, integer-partitions

I want to calculate distinct/odd partition of a given number n

According to the generating function i know

$$(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^3)(1+x^4)....(1+x^n)$$

After solving this the coefficient of $x^n$ will be the total number of distinct partition... But when i solve above expressions it's become extremely lengthy and also errors...

Anyone can tell me a general formula for this equation... So i can easily calculate Or any general formula for getting the total number of distinct partitions..

One thing that i know according Leonhard Euler the

number of total distinct partition = total number of odd partition of a given number

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory) ... why do you think it has a simple form?

Comment: how many possibilities are there to represent $k$ as a sum of distinct naturals less or equal $n$? (this gives the polynomial coefficients)

Comment: I don't know if  it has a simple form... I'm not found a way to solve it faster...  So i think maybe someone have anything  so i can make my calculation fast and error free

Comment: Take a look at the important results of Euler (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem).

Comment: i think there is a simple form. my idea to start with is: there is a minimum and a makimum $k$ such there exist decompositions in 2 components. what are the possible values of the 2 components? there is a minimum and a maximum $k$ such that there are 3 components. what are the possible values of the 3 components? iterate. (you can infer many combinations recurtsively)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionQ.html

In particular,
the function grows like
$\dfrac{e^{\pi\sqrt{n/3}}}{4\cdot3^{1/4}n^{3/4}}
$
and there is a
Rademacher-like convergent series.

Comment: I see link but not understand... Can you please explain me more about above function...